# What needs to go in order to fully remove a MAMP install from OSX?

Tags: macos, mamp, server-configuration

For reasons that we won't discuss, I have determined that MAMP is a pile of crap that haunts my system, and unless I remove it fully, I will live in shame.

I've done the obvious thing and removed the MAMP directory from my Applications folder, however, I don't like wandering files, and I have an itching feeling that MAMP put some .sock files somewhere, or otherwise made a mess in my file system.

**What files does MAMP add to a system when it's installed, and where are they?**

*If you have proof that MAMP doesn't actually put files anywhere (besides the /MAMP dir), then that's as good an answer as any!*

Comment: How do you prove that an application doesn't place a file anywhere? The opposite is easy.

Comment: It's proof enough if a MAMP developer/contributor can say one way or the other. This isn't the supreme court.

Comment: MAMP installed MySQL files to `/Application/Library/bin` that would only work when directed to the `/Application/MAMP` directory on my machine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From their [help page](http://www.mamp.info/en/help.html):

> To "uninstall" MAMP, you only have to
>   delete the MAMP directory and
>   everything returns to the original
>   state (MAMP does not alter anything on
>   the "normal" OS X).

Answer (score 4):

When you download MAMP, you get a MAMP Pro trial, also.  In the MAMP Pro folder, there is an 'uninstaller'.  When you open the uninstaller, it asks you if you would like to remove all traces (preferences, etc.)

When I used it, it appeared to delete absolutely everything for MAMP and MAMP Pro.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP does alter one system file: /etc/hosts (it adds any virtual hosts you may have created under the "hosts" tab here).

You may want to delete those entries.

To do so, go to Finder, select "Go"-"Folder" from the menu, and enter "/etc". Then you need to temporarily change permissions on both the host file and the directory it's in, by right clicking and chosing "Get info" and changing the permissions.

You can then edit the hosts file in Textedit.

After you're done, you should put the permissions back to what they were to be on the safe side.

Answer (score -1):

AppZapper is a great tool that solves this problem. Search Google for it, it's free for the first 5 time you use it.

Answer (score -1):

To fully uninstall any application. Try installing [AppTrap.](http://onnati.net/apptrap/) + it's free

Each time you move an application to Trash, AppTrap would find the preference files in your library and let you delete them as well.